# how to select element whose id contains | with jquery id selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

If an element id is `"mainid|label"`, it will throw exception when using `$("#mainid|label")`.

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #mainid|label
```

Then how to get this element with jquery id selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `$.escapeSelector`

```
$("#"+$.escapeSelector("mainid|label"))
```

`$.escapeSelector` automatically manage every single special character present in your string

Comment: Works from version `jQuery 3`

Answer (score 2):

Since | is a meta character, you have to escape it

```
 $("#mainid\\|label")
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

   > Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute, with any value.

```js
console.log($('[id="mainid|label"]').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='mainid|label'>mainid|label</span>
```